# Can’t log in: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response

Tags: support, openid, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Login to SO via Verisign failing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48022/login-to-so-via-verisign-failing)

I'm unable to log into my account using my OpenID, josh.gitlin.name on either StackOverflow or Meta. The error message I receive after entering my OpenID on the login page and pressing "Login" is:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct
>   message or getting the response

My alternate OpenID hmblprogrammer.pip.verisignlabs.com doesn't work either. I have been logged in for days on one computer (the one I am posting this from), however I am unable to log in from other computers. This issue started yesterday and I [posted this question to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717830/cant-log-in-error-occurred-while-sending-a-direct-message-or-getting-the-respon) because at the time I was on the road and unable to log in. It seems like at least one other user is having this issue.

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Luckily, i'm still logged into the meta site :)